# What is causing this PowerShell script error?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I'm writing a PowerShell script that registers and unregistered Scheduled Tasks on Windows Server 2012 R2. I'm in particular having trouble with this line:

```
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Sensei\"
```

(Sensei is the code name of this project, and is the name of the folder that contains all the tasks I care about.)

When I run that command from ISE or the command line, it works fine. However, when I run it from a `.ps1` file, it gives me a downright confusing error:

```
Unregister-ScheduledTask : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot bind argument to parameter 'TypeName' because it is null.
At Z:\server_scripts\clean.ps1:12 char:5
+     Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Sensei\"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Unregister-ScheduledTask], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Unregister-ScheduledTask
```

As near as I can tell, `TypeName` is not a parameter that `Unregister-ScheduledTask` accepts, so it must be coming from somewhere internal to the cmdlet.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

EDIT: Someone asked for the whole script. I omitted it since there's nothing else of note.

```
cd Z:\server_scripts
. .\variables.ps1

#Delete config files
    del $SENSEIPATH\assets.cfg
    del $SENSEIPATH\Web\Web.config

#Remove the virtual application
    Remove-WebApplication -Site $IISSITE -Name "c"

#Clean out the scheduled tasks
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Sensei\"
```

`.\variables.ps1` just contains a few variable definitions, such as `$SENSEIPATH` or `$IISSITE`. I can't post it here, but I promise there's nothing fancy.

Comment: Can you show us the entire contents of the script file?

Comment: Sure, but I doubt there's anything useful

Comment: How are you running the ps1 file. Just calling it from PowerShell?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the `DynamicParam` block in `Unregister-ScheduledTask`. Maybe it interprets the trailing slash as an escape sequence. Have you tried `-TaskPath "\Sensei"`

Comment: @JohandeHaan What do you mean by 'add'? That cmdlet is created by Microsoft

Comment: @Matt I have not, because it's currently being dynamically downloaded, executed and then deleted, but I'll give it a shot

Comment: @Matt Well, I'll be. I was running the script from ISE, but if I run it from the command line, it works. I'm not sure what that signifies. Maybe a problem with ISE?

Comment: I just wanted to know how it was being executed. I don't think that will change anything. Is "Sensei" in the root folder? You don't need the slashes

Comment: Was that a typo? Works in ISE but fails command line? Can you restart your ISE and does it still work after that.

Comment: Let me clarify: With "clean.ps1" as the script, if I run it in ISE, it gives the listed error. If I run it from powershell.exe, it executes correctly. (The slashes are necessary, don't ask me why)

Answer (score -1):

So, I don't understand what, exactly, the problem is, but here's what is going on.

I actually have a separate script, not listed above, that downloads the script in question, and then executes it. This is `bootstrap.ps1`. It looks something like this:

```
Read-S3Object -BucketName $BUCKET -Folder z:\server_scripts -KeyPrefix "server_scripts/app"

Z:\server_scripts\clean.ps1
```

When this ran from inside ISE, it would produce the error message above.

HOWEVER, if I ran `clean.ps1` directly, or ran `bootstrap.ps1` outside of ISE, OR I modified `bootstrap.ps1` like this, it works fine:

```
Read-S3Object -BucketName $BUCKET -Folder z:\server_scripts -KeyPrefix "server_scripts/app"

. Z:\server_scripts\clean.ps1
```

(I missed that some of these were succeeding because it throws a different error if `Unregister-ScheduledTask` doesn't find any tasks to unschedule, and wasn't paying close attention).

So, there might be some kind of scoping issue, but I am long past caring, and just want this thing to work. May this help someone else!